# Literal meaning of と-Particle in これより濃いと消毒する力

Tags: particle-と

This is a text from NHK easy news where the alcohol content of desinfectants is being discussed:

```
これより濃{こ}いと消毒{しょうどく}する力{ちから}が小{ちい}さくなるため、薄{うす}くして使{つか}うように言{い}っています。
```

I am wondering here about the literal translation of the と-Particle in これより濃{こ}い**と**消毒{しょうどく}する力{ちから}. Does the と-Particle in this case mean:

- WITH higher (alcohol) concentration than this (the desinfection efficacy will be smaller...), or
- IF the (alcohol) concentration is higer than this (the desinfection efficacy will be smaller...)

(So my question aims also a bit if this is how a proportionality relation, e.g. "with increasing speed the kinetic energy increases" can be expressed in Japanese)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think too strong alcohol contains less water to disinfect pathogen effectively (i.e. 70% concentration of alcohol works better than that of over 91%) .　[cf. This article : Why Is 70% the Most Effective Concentration of Isopropyl Alcohol for Disinfection?](https://blog.gotopac.com/2017/05/15/why-is-70-isopropyl-alcohol-ipa-a-better-disinfectant-than-99-isopropanol-and-what-is-ipa-used-for/). It explains "***The presence of water is a crucial factor in destroying or inhibiting the growth of pathogenic microorganisms with isopropyl alcohol...***"

Comment: It wouldn't use と in any way, but which do you mean, "with increasing speed that the" or "with increasing speed, the..."?

Comment: This と can only mean 'if' here. The meaning of 'with' would be ungrammatical when と follows a predicate.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth "with increasing speed(,) the kinetic energy increases" is equivalent to "as the speed increases, the kinetic energy increases".

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, thank you, so the former reading is (practically) impossible?

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth As a physicist who understand the meaning of kinetic energy, for me there is only one natural meaning to this sentence. The sentence fragment "with (the) increasing speed **that** the kinetic energy increases" sounds rather awkward. You could massage it into a grammatical sentence, but it would have to be a pretty weird context, and I think there would be more natural ways to express it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not explicitly expressing proportionality, it's just a conditional. Of course, constructions like this:

> これより濃いと消毒する力が小さくなる
>
> If the alcohol content is higher than this the disinfection efficacy will be smaller

In both English and Japanese do not exclude the possibility that there is a proportional relationship here between these two things, they just underspecify.

The thing most closely resembling the `with` you are asking about here, in terms of being relatively formal and expressing proportionality, is `とともに`. See [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB&pg=5) for some examples, like:

> 治療が長引くとともに増加する
>
> increase with prolonged therapy

Colloquially, proportional relationships can also be expressed with constructions like [すればするほど](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9).